# Routing in CakePHP 2.6.9

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.6, cakephp-2.x

I am using CakePHP 2.6.9.

I want to do following:

1. `www.example.com/detail/10` should refer to `controller => frontends` and `action => detail`
2. `www.example.com/admins/login` should refer to `controller => admins` and `action => login`

I edited `routes.php` as follows:

```php
Router::connect('/:action/*',
  array('controller' => 'frontends', 'action' =>'detail'));
```

But when I try `www.example.com/admins/login` it shows the following error:

> The action admins is not defined in controller FrontendsController

It proves that `www.example.com/admins/login` refers to

```
Router::connect('/:action/*',
  array('controller' => 'frontends', 'action' =>'detail'));
```

Routing. I want

```
Router::connect('/:action/*',
  array('controller' => 'frontends', 'action' =>'detail'));
```

will be only for `controller => frontends and action=>detail`, rest of url will work as default. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will do want you want.

```
Router::connect('/detail/*', array('controller' => 'Frontends', 'action' =>'detail'));
```

Mostly cakephp urls are like `/controller/action/id`. Your template of the route `/:action/*` tells that you are not using `controller names` in urls instead you are using only `action names` like `/detail/id` and `/admins/id`, and all actions are in `Frontends` controller. You can see from the error message that it tried to find `admins` action in `Frontends` conntroller.